# Can servlet return json and jsp in one response?

Tags: json, jsp, servlets

I'm new to servelt. What I do now is return a jsp file which contain js, then read json though ajax. I know servlet can return json and jsp, but can servlet return both json and jsp at the same time, so I don't need ajax to read the json.